# Return a fixed pointer in C#

Tags: c#, fixed, unsafe

I was wondering is it safe to return a fixed pointer from one method to another method - does the pinned object still stay fixed? e.g.

```
struct TestData
{
    public int value;
}

public class Class1
{
    private TestData data; 

    public unsafe TestData* GetDataPtr()
    {
        fixed (TestData* ptr = &data)
        {
            // IS THIS SAFE?
            return ptr; 
        }
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public unsafe void Test()
    {
        Class1 x = new Class1();

        TestData* ptr = x.GetDataPtr(); // is this still fixed?
        ptr->value = 2; 
    }
}
```

The reason i'm asking is using something in this style I've been getting AccessViolation exceptions. But since I changed it to e.g. set value direct from Class1 i haven't seen the issue occur.

EDIT:
the reason i thought it may be fixed is if from outside the "TestData* ptr = x.GetDataPtr()" you try to put fixed( ) you get "you cannot take the address of an already fixed expression". .. i get it now though it's speaking about my var "ptr" in "Test()" already being fixed..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Returning from the method ends the scope of `fixed`, hence the pointer is no longer fixed once you return. It is safe to pass fixed pointers up the chain, e.g.

```
fixed(TestData* ptr = &data) {
    MyFunction1(ptr);
    MyFunction2(ptr);
}
```

But returning makes the pointer non-fixed again.

Logically, this makes sense: there is no alternative way for the CLR to decide when the pointer should become non-fixed after you have returned it from the call.

Comment: That's a very good point, thanks! (see my EDIT as to why i thought it may be doing this)